# How to keep login throw Activities?

Tags: android, connection

I make login in my main activity.
If the login is correct, I wanna see my profile and download some data from server, but I cannot keep the connection, if I change activity.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Services are long running background tasks that live through Activities.

In your login form you could send a startService intent similar to starting a new activity. This calls `onStartCommand` on the Service class where you can create the connection and store it in the Service object itself. When you require information from the connection, you can acquire the service instance using `bindService` call.

Below is an example of a basic login service adapted from Google's basic example.

```
public class LocalService extends Service {

    private MyConnection conn;

    /**
     * Class for clients to access.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with
     * IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent i = new Intent("my.service.connected");
        try {
            conn = new MyConnection(
                intent.getStringExtra("username"),
                intent.getStringExtra("password"));
            i.putExtra("succeeded", true);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        } catch (ConnectionException ex) {
            i.putExtra("succeeded", false);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
    // RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
}
```

The Android.Manifest.xml also needs `<service android:name="LocalService"></service>` element inside the `<application />`.

Services don't come without their downsides though. Generally you should pass the startup parameters in an Intent which means they need to be serializable or parcelable. This prevents you from creating the connection in your Activity, checking that login succeeded and sending it the service.* Instead you need to send the login parameters to the service and perform the login there.

The complications come when you need to resolve whether the connection succeeded and you should proceed to the next activity or if it failed and you should show an error message. There are several solutions, but all of them require some setup. Especially when you consider that the user may **pause** your activity between pressing 'Login' and actually logging in.

As shown above, one option is to notify the activity by sending broadcasts from the Service. Below is an activity that launches the above service and listens to the broadcasts. The below activity does not take into account the possibility that the activity may be paused at any moment.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public final void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent i) {
            if (i.getBooleanExtra("succeeded", false)) {
                startMyMainActivity();
            } else {
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver bcReceiver;

    private void doLogin(String username, String password) {
        // Register receiver that listens for connected messages.
        bcReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter("my.service.connected");
        registerReceiver(bcReceiver, ifilter);

        // Send command to start service (connects)
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        i.putExtra("username", username);
        i.putExtra("password", password);
        startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (bcReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(bcReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

When the Activity should handle paused activity gracefully you should keep track of its state in a shared variable. If it was previously in a state where it tracked the Service it should bind to the Service and check its state when resuming. If the service is still connecting (as opposed to connected or disconnected) it should re-register the broadcast listener.

Comment: Can you make me an example?
I'm not really good with Android dev.

Comment: Thank you.
Now I try it on Eclipse with the other way, and I choose the best :)

Comment: With HTTP connections you are probably better off with Eddie's solution as long as you store the Session cookie as well. Services are better when you really need to hold onto a connection object, such as some stateful TCP connection. They are powerful concepts but might add too much complexity for simple applications.

Answer (score 1):

Once you verify the login is correct (by testing the connection to the server and 
authenticating), you can store the login details in SharedPreferences or something similar.

Then you can just make subsequent requests using those login details (no matter which activity you are in). This is, of course, assuming the server accepts authentication this way.

Comment: Check this Login activity I wrote for my GitHub app:

https://github.com/eddieringle/hubroid/blob/next/src/org/idlesoft/android/hubroid/activities/Login.java

Comment: Wow.
Pretty good and very clean code :)
But, so, i don't understand what i've to do in the next activity.
If in the second activity I have to download some post, like twitter, how can I use the same session for make this thing?

Comment: Check out the SharedPreference doc for more information on how to set and read preferences: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I understand all Eddie ;)
But,when I put my user and pass into SharedPreferences, how can I keep the session??
I have to do login in each activities?

Comment: The data you want to collect is session-dependent? You can't just make another request to the server with those saved login details to get the data you need?

Comment: Yes, because if I logged in correctly, I show a "stream", like twitte's/Facebook's stream, with the download of the post.
Understand the situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If you can authenticate correctly and store the authentication details, what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need to keep the connection. Maybe you can just reopen the connection and login again?

But if you really need to keep the connection open: You could can keep the connection in the Application. But make sure you close the connection when the user goes away from your app! I really don't recommend this. Or set a timeout for the connection to be closed like after 5 minutes of inactivity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

You will have to say in the AndroidManifest which Application your App uses.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm (see andriod:name).

Then you can get the application from the activity through: getApplication(). Don't forget to cast it. Than add functions where you can login and so on.

**Edit:**

A little more detailed:

You will have to create a class extending Application. The name of this class you enter in the android:name of the application in the manifest. In that class you write functions with which you handle the connection. Like: startConnection() doLogin() stopConnection() ... In the Activities you call:

```
NameOfYouApplication app = (NameOfYouApplication) getApplication();
app.startConnection();
app.doLogin();
```

kind of like that. But beware that even if the Activity is closed your Application will stay alive. You better find a good time to close the connection.

Comment: I don't understand at all.
Can you explain me with an example?

Comment: hmm.. to explain how to do it exactly would take quite a long time. But let me add a short thing above in the post to help you a little.

Comment: really as i said. better is to login again in the second activity. another response tells you how to do that. I assume in this answer, that you HAVE TO keep the connection alive (for whatever reason).

Comment: And how I can close the connection?

And, other question, for exaple:
I create the NetUtilities class, with:
startconnection()
doLogin
methods.
In my main application, I make login with user/pass (passed as params to doLogin method), when I see the new Activity, how I keep the connection?

Comment: Sorry. But just go with the idea in the answer by Eddie Ringle. I am pretty sure that is what you need! I thought you WANT and NEED to keep the connection open. But I think your post is misleading and it is okay to open a new connection and do the login again in the second activity.